# React: Read configurations from external file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to implement a solution for reading configurations from some file in my react app... don't know what is the best practice but I adapted the following way and tried implementing it:

1) under the root of my app (in parallel to webpack.config.js)
I created a file called: config.dev.json with this content:

> {
>     "protocol" : "http",
>     "host" : "localhost",
>     "port" : "8080"
>   }

2) to webpack.config.js added my code (TODO part at the end):

```
 const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const rtlcss = require('rtlcss');
const webpack = require("webpack");

const useExternalCss =
  process.env.CARBON_REACT_STORYBOOK_USE_EXTERNAL_CSS === 'true';

const useStyleSourceMap =
  process.env.CARBON_REACT_STORYBOOK_USE_STYLE_SOURCEMAP === 'true';

const useRtl = process.env.CARBON_REACT_STORYBOOK_USE_RTL === 'true';

const styleLoaders = [
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      importLoaders: 2,
      sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
    },
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      plugins: () => {
        const autoPrefixer = require('autoprefixer')({
          browsers: ['last 1 version', 'ie >= 11'],
        });
        return !useRtl ? [autoPrefixer] : [autoPrefixer, rtlcss];
      },
      sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
    },
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules')],
      data: `
        $feature-flags: (
          ui-shell: true,
        );
      `,
      sourceMap: useStyleSourceMap,
    },
  },
];

module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.devtool = useStyleSourceMap ? 'source-map' : '';
  defaultConfig.optimization = {
    ...defaultConfig.optimization,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
        },
      }),
    ],
  };

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /-story\.jsx?$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader'),
        options: {
          prettierConfig: {
            parser: 'babylon',
            printWidth: 80,
            tabWidth: 2,
            bracketSpacing: true,
            trailingComma: 'es5',
            singleQuote: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    enforce: 'pre',
  });

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    sideEffects: true,
    use: [
      { loader: useExternalCss ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader' },
      ...styleLoaders,
    ],
  });

  if (useExternalCss) {
    defaultConfig.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      })
    );
  }

  //TODO
  if (!defaultConfig.resolve) {
    defaultConfig.resolve = {};
  }
  if (!defaultConfig.resolve.alias) {
    defaultConfig.resolve.alias = {};
  }
  defaultConfig.resolve.alias.Config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? path.resolve('./config.prod.json')
      : path.resolve('./config.dev.json');


  return defaultConfig;
};

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
        'BASE_URL': JSON.stringify('http://localhost:3000/')
      }
    })
  ],

//   externals: {
//     'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))
//   }
//
//   // externals: {
//   //   'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {
//   //     serverUrl: "http://test.com:8080"
//   //   } : {
//   //     serverUrl: "http://localhost:8080"
//   //   })
//   // }
//

}
```

3) and tried to use it from some component that way:

```
let Config = require('Config')
```

but I'm getting:

> ./src/stores/RestService.js
>   Module not found: Can't resolve 'Config' in 'C:

Answer (score 5):

If you want to setup configuration without webpack (e.g. when using create-react-app) this is how I'd suggest:

Create config folder (or name it however you want) and add your config files and index file:

- config.dev.json
- config.prod.json
- index.js

And then inside your config/index.js file:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    module.exports = require('./config.dev.json')
} else {
    module.exports = require('./config.prod.json')
}
```

Use it with `import config from './config';`

Comment: I called it Config.js instead of index.js, and located the config folder out of src folder (it's recommended when installing the production on customer site) then used this import: import config from '../../config/Config'; and I got: Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported

Comment: I guess that you can use webpacks DefinePlugin then, but I'm not sure why it's recommended to have config outside src folder?

Comment: I didn't manage yet to figure how to make it works with Webpack as it was suggested in remix23 solution. However, my concern about not including the configs inside src is because we have installer, and base on what the user fill in for protocol://host:port values from the installation wizard we should use them before deploying the final app... what happens If I don't want to give the src to customer? I mean to do > npm run build, and use the output in some war to be deployed on some container like tomcat or whatever...

Comment: if I put config files under src your solution works

Answer (score 1):

why not use like this

1. at your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "develop": "PORT=8080 HOST=localhost PROTOCOL=http node ."
    "production": "Your config here"
}
```

2. create a config/app.js

```
    const config = process.env
    module.export = {
         port: config.PORT,
         protocol: config.PROTOCOL,
         host: config.HOST,
    }
```

3. In your webpack ( actually, i don't know why you have to import config in your webpack and reexport it. if you want your jsx or js files able to read the PORT, HOST, and LOCALHOST, u can just follow until step 2, and u can freely get your config files in any your app.js files )

```
const config = require('./path/to/config/app.js')

module.exports = {
     externals: {
          config: config,
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. where to use the relative path? "./config.dev.json" is relative!

Comment: Sorry, i didn't read the last part of your webpack configuration

Comment: and Yes, like remix23 answer, u should use resolver configuration
````
resolver:{
    config: require('./path/to/config)
}
````

but sometimes i found that resolver didn't work on my app, so i used babel-resolver instead. it's provide same functionality too.

Answer (score 1):

First you need the configuration file in your bundle, it's not an external (so we only need to remove the external part).

Then you need the config file to be resolved as a diffrent file depending on the environment (prod or dev, using [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)).

Be carefull of the working directory too, either run webpack from the project's folder, or use the [context](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#context) configuration option.

Suggested webpack config (relevant part in the end):

```
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.devtool = useStyleSourceMap ? 'source-map' : '';
  defaultConfig.optimization = {
    ...defaultConfig.optimization,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        terserOptions: {
          mangle: false,
        },
      }),
    ],
  };

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /-story\.jsx?$/,
    loaders: [
      {
        loader: require.resolve('@storybook/addon-storysource/loader'),
        options: {
          prettierConfig: {
            parser: 'babylon',
            printWidth: 80,
            tabWidth: 2,
            bracketSpacing: true,
            trailingComma: 'es5',
            singleQuote: true,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
    enforce: 'pre',
  });

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    sideEffects: true,
    use: [
      { loader: useExternalCss ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader' },
      ...styleLoaders,
    ],
  });

  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.json$/,
    use: [
      { loader: useExternalCss ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader' },
      ...styleLoaders,
    ],
  });


  if (useExternalCss) {
    defaultConfig.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      })
    );
  }
  // ensure resolve alias present in the config
  if (!defaultConfig.resolve) {
      defaultConfig.resolve = {};
  }
  if (!defaultConfig.resolve.alias) {
      defaultConfig.resolve.alias = {};
  }
  // resolve the alias to the right config file according to NODE_ENV
  // you'll have to correctly set <relative path to your config>
  defaultConfig.resolve.alias.Config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? path.resolve(__dirname, '<relative path to your config>/config.prod.json')
      : path.resolve(__dirname, '<relative path to your config>/config.dev.json');


  return defaultConfig;
};
```

don't forget to remove this:

```
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? require('./config.prod.json') : require('./config.dev.json'))
  }

  // externals: {
  //   'Config': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {
  //     serverUrl: "http://test.test.com:8080"
  //   } : {
  //     serverUrl: "http://localhost:8080"
  //   })
  // }

}
```

As it will prevent webpack from bundling the file.

Comment: Can you please give a hint how to use these configurations later on from component

Comment: `let Config = require('Config')`, as you wanted to.

Comment: I added your part as suggested, but still getting Module not found when doing require('Config')!!!

Comment: Which webpack version are you using? Prior to version 2 you need a loader for json files.

Comment: I thought that webpack is installed already! cause when running webpack -v from terminal I got a message that I should install webpack-cli, so after I installed it now I got 4.28.3 as version, but still the same behavior!

Comment: Are you sure you removed `Config` from externals (as it will prevent the config file to be bundled)?

Comment: Yes. removed for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198725/discussion-between-remix23-and-zbeedatm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefinePlugin to define setting config in webpack like this

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
            'BASE_URL': JSON.stringify('http://localhost:5000/')
        }
    })
],
```

Then simply use

```
process.env.BASE_URL
```

or

```
process.env.NODE_ENV
```

Comment: I saw this approach while seeking, but didn't know how to include plugins section in my webpack cause it seems different... where to put it? inside module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => { ??

Comment: Yes put in the module.exports section

Comment: You can read my blog here https://ngohungphuc.wordpress.com/2019/03/26/webpack-enviroment-configuration/

Comment: I did as you suggested (edited my post with updated webpack), but got undefined when trying to get the value of : process.env.BASE_URL !

Comment: maybe I'm missing some webpack dependencies that need to be installed? or it's something wrong with my webpack file structure?